# Does eclipse have a debugger "step into selected" option that prompts for the method to step into?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, intellij-idea

I have used IntelliJ Idea on a few projects and I really like the feature it has in the debugger where I can step into a line of code, but choose which of the methods I REALLY want to step into, instead of going through them all until I hit the one I want.

For example, the debugger stops at this line:

```
String restult = getMyResult(getParam(), buildSomething(), nextOption(x));
```

I want to hit ctrl+F5 and have a list popup with:

- getMyresult()
- getParam()
- buildSomething()
- nextOption()

and I can select getMyResult and step into that method while skipping the other three.

It sure miss that feature when I am debugging in eclipse, does anyone know if there is something comparable?

I know about the Step Filtering options in Eclipse, but that is not quite what I want.

Comment: I don't know about Eclipse, but Visual Studio puts it on the right-button menu.  Perhaps Eclipse is the same?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply put a cursor on method you want and hit Ctrl-F5, so no additional selection needed. 
Alternatively you can use Ctrl+Alt-Clik using mouse do do the same.

Comment: awesome.  that works good enough.  CMD+F5 on mac for anyone interested.

Comment: Shortcut for "Step into selection" is currently (Eclipse 4.3) alt-F5.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- Select the text of the method call you want to jump into
- Then right-click into context menu
- Choose "Step into selection" from there.

Does not work all of the time tho.

Answer (score -1):

In IntelliJ Idea 10.5
It is called **Smart Step Into**
In menu it can be found "*Run -> Smart Step Into*"

Comment: The question is "how do you do this Eclipse?"  The question explains how to do it in IntelliJ.