# Select which method to "Step Into" in debugger

Tags: eclipse, debugging, netbeans, step-into

Netbeans has a nice "Step Into" feature where if there are multiple method calls on the same line, you can use the arrow keys to choose which one you meant. You can see a screenshot and description on [this new and noteworthy page](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteWorthyMilestone2NB65#Step_Into_action_redesign).

I am wondering, does Eclipse have the same feature? I see that Eclipse does have Step Filtering, but that's not the same. I prefer not to  F5, F7, F5, ...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826089/ (which has no answers, so I suspect the answer is "No").

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Eclipse had it for ages. While debugger is stopped on a break point, put cursor on a method you want to step into and then use Run menu / Step Into Selection (Ctrl-F5) or just Ctrl+Alt-Click on that method in the editor.

Comment: Are you sure? I tried both methods on the line `Paths.get("/tmp/nonExistantDirectory/nonExistantFile").createFile();` and the debugger always went immediately into `Paths.get()`.

Comment: Positive. I use it all the time. Just hit it few minutes ago.

Comment: @Steve, you need to have the cursor on createFile() when pressing Ctrl-F5.

Comment: As a side node, it's kinda buggy when the methods are all in a single line.  Put them in different lines and all will be good.  By buggy I mean: if you have more than one call to the same method on a line, clicking on any of them will stop at the first occurence.  Also you can use the _step into selection_ feature only once per line: the second click will resume the execution, and only stop at your selection if by chance the program goes back to that point.